# Autocomplete is matching word starting only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code is about Autocomplete with an external JSON array. My problem is that the autocomplete only displays when I entered the first two initial words. For example, I want to find the capital "Kabul", I have to enter "Ka" to find the capital in the autocomplete. If I enter "ab" or " bu", it won't show "Kabul". Please help me.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#answer").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var display = [];
      $.each(array, function(k, v) {
        if (v.capital.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
          display.push({ "label": v.capital });
          return;
        }
      });
      response(display);
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because `indexOf` will return the zero-based index of the occurrence of the string you're looking for, or `-1` if it's not found. Therefore your use of `== 0` in the `if` condition will only hit when the search string is found at the start of the source.

To amend this behaviour change the condition to `!== -1`,:

```
if (v.capital.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) !== 1) {
```

Comment: if the above solution is working fine then mark it as right  so that it will helps to others.